# component is not rendering after the imports and export of module in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular12

The angular component is not rendering, I have declared and exported a component in my `header-module.ts` and imported that module to anther module but I still get the error.

I have restarted the the server and vscode several times but I still cant get rid of this error anyone please help me I have been stuck in this for a long time.

```
Error: join-sign-in.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <app-header></app-header>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  join-sign-in.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './join-sign-in.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component JoinSignInComponent.
```

Comment: Can you share a little bit of the code for how the component is built and where it is registered at?  All you've shown is a description and an error message which is diffcult to give advice based only on that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.